# Create pfile from spfile

Tags: oracle

I want to create pfile from spfile (`oracle\product\11.2.0\server\dbs`) then I want to see and edit it and then create spfile new from pfile.
Is it possible? How?

```
CREATE pfile='G:/my_init.ora' FROM spfile;
```

Error: 
**SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges**

> 1031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
>
> *Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
>              the necessary privileges.
>
> *Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
>              administrator to grant you the necessary privileges

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are connected to the server on which oracle is running, try using sqlplus like so - `sqlplus / as sysdba`.
It will allow you to connect with the required privileges to run this statement.

Answer (score 3):

The message is rather clear. Not sufficient privileges.

From [`CREATE PFILE doc`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6008.htm)

> You must have the **SYSDBA** or the **SYSOPER** role to execute this
>   statement. You can execute this statement either before or after
>   instance startup.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error while connected as sysdba, but I forgot that in the interim before I invoked the `create pfile`  command, I had been timing some SQL statements and had invoked the `set autotrace on` at one point, then did a `set autotrace off` later, then tried the `create pfile` command and got the `ORA-01031` error.  A simple reconnect as sysdba fixed it:

```
SYS@extuat01> create pfile = 'pinitextuat01_from_mem.ora' from memory;
create pfile = 'pinitextuat01_from_mem.ora' from memory
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

SYS@extuat01> connect / as sysdba
Connected.
SYS@extuat01> create pfile = 'pinitextuat01_from_mem.ora' from memory;

File created.

SYS@extuat01>
```